# Undefined columns error when performing TukeyHSD

Tags: r, anova, tukey

I'm extremely new to R and need your help!

I performed an Anova/Factorial Anova and wanted to do a Tukey test however I got this error:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(mf, mf.cols[[i]]) : undefined columns selected
```

Here is what I did for the anova and such (removed section testing for normality)

````
> data.aov<- aov(`FREQUENCY OF INGESTION` ~ `HYDROLOGY REGIME`*`DEPTH ZONE`*`ST. LOCATION`)
> anova(data.aov)
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: FREQUENCY OF INGESTION
                                Df Sum Sq   Mean Sq F value  Pr(>F)  
`HYDROLOGY REGIME`                1 0.0002 0.0001530  0.0218 0.88274  
`DEPTH ZONE`                      3 0.0147 0.0049134  0.6990 0.55288  
`ST. LOCATION`                    1 0.0202 0.0201579  2.8677 0.09085 .
`HYDROLOGY REGIME`:`DEPTH ZONE`   2 0.0229 0.0114514  1.6291 0.19691  
`DEPTH ZONE`:`ST. LOCATION`       1 0.0018 0.0017877  0.2543 0.61422  
Residuals                       651 4.5761 0.0070293                  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
> TukeyHSD(data.aov)
Error in `[.data.frame`(mf, mf.cols[[i]]) : undefined columns selected
> library(multcompView)
> multcompLetters(extract_p(TukeyHSD(aov(`FREQUENCY OF INGESTION`~`HYDROLOGY REGIME`*`DEPTH ZONE`*`ST. LOCATION`))) ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Try using the TukeyC package. There are several facilities compared to other packages for factorial experiments, split-plot and etc. Follow the link: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/TukeyC/TukeyC.pdf

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31253552)